# How do I import an existing GIT project into SVN, preserving GIT history on master branch?

Tags: svn, git, import

I've a project developed with GIT and have a few hundred commits. I only have one master branch and the commits are linear.

Now I'm asked to put the source into an existing SVN and ultimately I'd like to preserve the master commit history (the messages and the diffs, author is preset by SVN access).

It's like I need to replay the whole commit history into SVN. Is there a way from GIT to do this more or less automatic?

One idea came to my mind, but I've no clue how to approach it: I create a new empty `trunk/` in SVN, clone it with GIT (i.e. an empty GIT SVN clone) and replay my master changes into it and than dcommit it.

In the future I'll do further work with my GIT branch and synchronize it with SVN.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you moving from git to svn?

Comment: @Zachary: In my view, I'm not moving the project: I was asked by the ones I developed this for to put it into their SVN. And, ideally, I'd like to preserve the history. I'll continue developing with GIT in the future, but then do regularly push into their SVN. Getting everything *somehow* into SVN and checking it out with GIT is fine for me too.

Comment: Trailblazing dev, hungry for new experience, starts using Git locally. Loves it. Uses it to build a prototype for two weeks. Business likes the prototype, says 'What is this Git thing? What's wrong with SVN? Get it into our SVN Repo, but keep all that useful commit history.'
Seen it happen more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a very detailed tutorial on how to do this [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017153509/http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit). It is for importing to Google code, but will work for any svn repo.

Comment: Unfortunately the page does not exist anymore. Do you know another ressource for that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up empty SVN project with some commit.
2. "git svn clone" it.
3. Import history in that almost-empty git-svn project (rebase here)
4. "git svn dcommit".

Issues:

1. timestamps are broken, author names are broken.
2. "git svn dcommit" works not so good when there are too much commits to dcommit. Splitting to packs of about 20 commits each is preferred.